# Why do I receive "Error: cannot find symbol import com.wa.delxott.R"?

Tags: java, r, react-native, android-studio, android-native-library

```
Error: cannot find symbol import com.wa.delxott.R
                        
Symbol:   class R
Location: package com.wa.delxott
```

After I change package name, during app resking. I try to check clear and rebuild, but I am getting same error. I've lost my 7 hours for this error. Is there any way to fix this it?

In `download fragment.java` R is highlighted as a red colour error:

```java
import com.orhanobut.hawk.Hawk; 
import com.wa.delxott.Provider.AndroidWebServer; 
import com.wa.delxott.R; 
import com.wa.delxott.entity.DownloadItem; 
import com.wa.delxott.ui.Adapters.DownloadedAdapter; 
import com.wa.delxott.ui.activities.PlayerActivity;
```

Comment: Hi please add portion of code that causes this error.

Comment: *import com.orhanobut.hawk.Hawk;
import com.wa.delxott.Provider.AndroidWebServer;*
*import com.wa.delxott*.**R**;
*import com.wa.delxott.entity.DownloadItem;
import com.wa.delxott.ui.Adapters.DownloadedAdapter;
import com.wa.delxott.ui.activities.PlayerActivity;*

Comment: No Wasim, not here, but in your question. You have to add that

Comment: It's impossible to tell that way, what is it exactly. There is no known `com.wa.delxott` package, I suppose it's some inside development of yours or your company. The error means that there is no `R` class in `com.wa.delxott` package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:r]?